# SSIS package finished successfully with skipping several tasks

Tags: ssis, etl

ETL package finished successfully without execution of several last tasks:
[image]

Then I've tried to run task with the same type and skip other:
[image]

After that I've created separate package with the last five tasks and they run great as expected!
[image]

**Question:**
What's happen with the flow on the first two figures? Why does package skip several tasks without any warnings/errors etc.?

Thanks a lot for answers and any ideas about this strange behavior!

**[UPDATE]** **Answered by @Peter_R**:
I've changed both **sp_updatestats** inputs from AND to OR and everything is ok. Arrows was changed to dotted ones:
[image: FIXED]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Logical AND constraint requires all tasks to complete before running so you `SP_Updatestats` will not run until both `ProcessFull` and `MeasureGroupSet Loop` have completed.

I am guessing after `Deploy Data` the Expression is designed to split the workflow depending on a condition you have set. In doing this you will never have both `ProcessFull` and `MeasureGroupSet Loop` running in parallel, meaning that the `SP_UpdateStats` task will never run.

If you change both the connecting constraints to the `SP_UpdateStats` to `Logical OR` it will run after either the `ProcessFull` OR `MeasureGroupSet Loop` has completed.

This is still the case if something is disabled as well, slightly odd but still the case.

Comment: You are completely right! I forgot to switch both arrows to OR-condition. Thanks, you saved my brain from explosion! Have a nice day!